# From Objective C to C++ typing headache

Tags: c++, json, objective-c, polymorphism

I have worked in C++ but it were some years ago, last 5 or so years I've almost only been working in Objective C and perhaps I've just gotten comfortable doing so.

However I am writing a C++ json-parser and it is conceptually difficult since there is no natural mapping as there is in Objective C. I am not saying it's better one way or the other, just stating that I haven't found a natural mapping.

So in Objective C I would typically start parsing json as a NSDictionary since it maps really well. An NSDictionary is a key-value pair datatype, where the key typically is a string (but can be any type) and the value is typically an NSObject (conceptually), and in Objc everything inherits NSObject so types are kind of "auto-polymorphic" if you will. (explanation given for any C++ developer which might know exactly how to help me but don't understand what I am asking for if I don't explain Objc).

Anyhow this mean that if I have an example json-string:

```
{"key":1, "key2":3.14, "key3":"hello world", "key4":[1,2,3]}
```

it already maps exactly onto an NSDictionary where the first value would be an integer (or number) second a float (or number) third an NSString, and 4th would be an NSArray which hold three values which happens to be integers in my example but could be anything at all as long as it's derived from NSObject.

In C++ this is much harder for me to understand and find a good mapping or model for, I guess I could roll my own polymorphic types to do the same thing, then I can have a map with the abstract type and get pretty much the same behaviour.

But either I am thinking that I will need to write my own containers (map and vectors) or write my own "Json-types". However I am a bit afraid to be all too stuck in the way of thinking which is right in Objc, since it's a very different language and built on completely different design ideas then C++.

Maybe there is better and more correct ways to do stuff like this in C++ which I just don't know. So my questions is how to handle things which may have different types in a good way in C++.

Comment: Maybe Boost.Variant or Boost.Any could help?

Comment: Aha... That is what I did around a year ago.

I had an XML having a structure of classes for java, I parsed it and created classes of Objective-C. This took 2 days to write but, 100s of model-classes got converted in just few clicks.

Comment: @piwi isn't boost a lot of dependencies? I did look at it, mainly for the `any` type thinking that maybe I would be able to have stl `vector` and `map` template arguments typed to boost `any` type and get the polymorph-like behaviours, but I am a bit uncomfortable to add such a huge library just to solve for something like this.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya I am not sure I understand fully what it was that you did? Did you implement polymorphic classes in java to get an objective-c `NSDictionary` -like behaviour?

Comment: No. I read the .java file and created .h and .m for obj-c. Here you need to create C++ file/parser from obj-c.

Comment: @qrikko Actually most of the Boost components are header-only, so it ususally requires nothing more than including the proper headers; in this case, neither any nor variant need linking; also, you can install only portions of Boost, not everything

Comment: @AnoopVaidya ah! I see and maybe it really is the way to go, I have been thinking along those lines, it keep my dependencies clean which I value. But perhaps I will do just that, implement my own datatypes which work like the `NSDictionary, NSArray` and so on, basically add some syntactical sugar to my C++ project.

Comment: @qrikko: Why your own? Try `std::vector` and `std::map`.

Comment: Or you can write a parser in obj-c. Write the output to a file. And read that file from C++. If may help you a bit? But I am not sure.

Comment: @piwi that is great information, and it makes it a much more attractive alternative. I don't want to skip great functionality just to be a I-don't-want-dependencies guy, but I do want to know what I take into the project and why. But I will take another, bit deeper, look into Boost since it does seem to solve my problems in an elegant and quite comfortable way.

Comment: @Linuxios I am wanting to use the `std::vector` and `std::map` but I've been exposed to Objc and the inheritance model for some time, and the `vector` in json may have any type for the objects inside it. So this maps well to objc `NSArray` may have any object as long as it is derived from `NSObject` while in C++ I need to know the type beforehand (since the typing is much harder in C++). so I can do: `std::vector<int>` to keep integers but the json array may have one `int`, then a `string`, and so on. That's why I am trying to find a way that works for both me and C++. (hope that made sense)

Comment: @qrikko: So use an std::vector of boost::any.

Comment: @Linuxios yes that seem to be the way to do it. I was afraid that Boost would give me a big dependency but as piwi pointed out it really isn't because of the way it's implemented. So I will read through some of the documentation of Boost but from my answers here it does look like it is the way to go, which will make both me and C++ happy.

Comment: @qrikko: You'll learn that there isn't much that makes C++ happy or terribly usable. It can be hell.

Comment: @Linuxios yeah I guess.. I find it really difficult being a bit spoiled by the more loosely typed objc where anything really can be casted to whatever you need it to be and polymorphism is kind of expected rather then enforced (or what I should call the way C++ handles polymorphism). But many times I feel when I look at a problem in C++ that in another language such as ruby, Lua, or Objc I see at once how to tackle it, in C++ I feel that there are alway that little 'but' in the way. I can parse json using `std::map` but then I need to restrict the types. But Boost may bridge my understanding.

Comment: see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245973/whats-the-best-c-json-parser), if you didn't already. You'll be the judge of which one's the best fit for your needs, or as an inspiration for your own implementation if you wish to do it.

Comment: @didierc it actually does touch a lot of my concerns/questions and does make it clearer thanks.

Comment: @qrikko: Agreed. I started to prefer C for the "everything is a blob of bits" philosophy. it allows you to do much more.

Comment: @Linuxios Yes that does have some really nice benefits to it, it's a bit tedious I guess and I am not at all used to thinking like that but could see myself get into it. It does allow for very nice access and a small set of crazy possibilities (i.e. there aren't 2k ways to do the same thing). But again I am not really used to thinking like that even if I like it as an idea and believe I could become used to it... :P

Comment: @qrikko: True, true. I could talk for days about this. If you want to, we can make a chat thread where it won't get deleted for being irrelevant to question.

Comment: @Linuxios I'm always up for learning and to what extent I can also share my experience. :)

Comment: @qrikko: if you want a chat room I'll create one.

Comment: @Linuxios I don't know how to, so please go ahead.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21834/discussion-between-linuxios-and-qrikko)

Comment: Not useful for OP since this is proprietary source, but I wanted to mention that the code base we are using in our 13 years small company *is a direct mapping of Objective-C core classes re-implemented into C++*. Including autorelease pools, which proved very handy and a viable alternative to manual memory management or C++11 smart pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all a disclaimer, when I talk about Objective C here I really include a lot of Cocoa I think that most readers will seamlessly read this into it, but just to be clear when I talk about Cocoa specific stuff calling it Objective C it's just that I am really used to using Cocoa along with Objective C (i.e. OSX development).

Well I've got some input and the solution I am probably going with here is to adept to `Boost`. So this would mean that I parse my `json dictionaries` as `std::map <std::string, boost::any>` and my arrays/vectors as `std::vector <boost::any>` and this will loosen up the hard typing to a level which is more fitting for a data description format such as json.

Thanks to all the people commenting and helping out here!

The great thing is that even if this is for my json-parser it really have given me more perspective so I feel that there are similar problems I've experienced from being spoiled in coding in languages which are less strongly typed, and have a more open (or closed I guess depending on how you see it) object architecture. Hope that others will find this question useful as well!